# Find duplicate column multiple value in db

Tags: sqlite, sql-delete

I have a sqlite db with the following columns:

```
id   home   path    name    layer
1   /home   test    user1   1
2   /etc    test2   user2   1
3   /home   test    user3   1
4   /home   test    user4   1
5   /home   test    user1   1
6   /etc    test2   user2   1
```

How can I delete all duplicates, if `home`, `path` and `name` be equal, but only if all 3 be the same?

Sl id 1 should be deleted because its a duplicate of id 5 and id 2 delete because it's a duplicate of id 6.

This is how it should look like:

```
id   home   path    name    layer
3   /home   test    user3   1
4   /home   test    user4   1
5   /home   test    user1   1
6   /etc    test2   user2   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by the columns `home`, `path`, `name` and select `MAX(id)`.
In this case SQLite will return for each combination of the 3 columns only 1 row which is the one with the max `id`:

```
SELECT MAX(id) id, home, path, name, layer
FROM tablename
GROUP BY home, path, name
ORDER BY id
```

This is a [documented feature of SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_select.html#simple_select_processing).

If you want to delete the duplicates:

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tablename GROUP BY home, path, name)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=71df6eafdc6d2c8cfb3110c8e214c230).
Results:

| id | home | path | name | layer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | /home | test | user3 | 1 |
| 4 | /home | test | user4 | 1 |
| 5 | /home | test | user1 | 1 |
| 6 | /etc | test2 | user2 | 1 |

Comment: Invalid: You are selecting `layer`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There is no problem with this. It is a documented feature of SQLite.

Comment: the command does not show the duplicates, but i want to remove them from the db

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `group by`:

```sql
select
  *
from data

group by "home", "path", "name"
having max("id")

order by "id"
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f16ad/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to *delete* the duplicates, then use exists logic:

```sql
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.home = yourTable.home AND
                    t2.path = yourTable.path AND
                    t2.name = yourTable.name AND
                    t2.id > yourTable.id);
```

If you just want to *view* your data this way, then try:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                  WHERE t2.home = t1.home AND t2.path = t1.path AND
                        t2.name = t1.name AND t2.id > t1.id);
```

Comment: error on Delete : near "t1": syntax error

Comment: You are not running my actual answer, and the answer you accepted has serious problems.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the OP is using your actual answer which has serious problems: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e4391cecf81a3d05e6e28334a3f41f49